# Pending workflow Approvals Items List

Tags: workflow

In a scenario, using DXF 100’s of products get added/updated to the content tree, added on the workflow, approval process.

As a Content Authors what are the options I have to get list of pending approval items, with out going to each tree node. I would like hear about Sitecore Out of Box capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the WorkBox:

> The Workbox is a tool for reviewing and managing items that are in a
>   workflow. When you need to review your items, use the Workbox to see
>   all the items that are currently in workflows and the workflow states
>   that they are in.

All info can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/review_an_item_in_the_workbox
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/the_workbox_commands

It does allow bulk operations which might help you as you seem to have lots of items.

> Before you publish a content item on your website, commands in the
>   Workbox let you preview, open, or compare different versions of an
>   item, as well as approve or reject the content.
>
> Some commands can be executed on many items at the same time, and only
>   certain commands are shown for all items, while others appear
>   depending on the workflow commands configured for the corresponding
>   workflow state.
>
> In the Workbox, in the Workflows section, you can configure the
>   Workbox to only show specific workflows.

[image]

You can open the Workbox from the Launchpad.